# Host CPU use optimization on KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, smp

I've done KVM based virtualization setup with following configuration.

```
HOST Machine
----------------
OS: CentOS 6.6 (64-bit)
CPU:  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5606  @ 2.13GHz
RAM: 32 GBs
Disk: 2 TBs (LVM-based)
```

CPU support hardware virutalization & its already enabled.

```
[root@setup-01 ~]# grep -c  vmx /proc/cpuinfo 
8
```

KVM modules are loaded

```
[root@setup-01 ~]# lsmod | grep kvm
kvm_intel              55496  64 
kvm                   337900  1 kvm_intel
```

I'm running 32 virutal machines on this host, after experiacing slowness I observed only single CPU is being utilized on Host machine. Rest are idle.

```
top - 11:05:39 up 7 days, 20:31,  1 user,  load average: 14.58, 15.04, 13.40
Tasks: 258 total,  13 running, 245 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  : 46.2%us, 53.8%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  0.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  :  0.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32811436k total, 14290408k used, 18521028k free,   119924k buffers
Swap:  8290300k total,        0k used,  8290300k free,  2549308k cached
```

Is there any setting is required to make sure KVM is taking full advantage of multi-processor environment. Let me know if more information is required for setup.

Comment: [33.8. Setting KVM processor affinities](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/ch33s08.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After verifying base guest configuration file (xml) found the problem.

```
<vcpu placement='static' cpuset='2'>1</vcpu>
```

Since I used same template for creating all VMs after cloning, all VMs were using same CPU.